# Getting undefined string constraint error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, innerhtml

I want to pass a Javascript variable as a argument of a function called on `onclick` event of a checkbox, and the checkbox is created in innerHTML.
The code snippet is:

```
function populateValue(Result) {
    var valueSet = new Array();
    valueSet = Result.split("##");
    for (i = 1; i < valueSet.length - 3; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        tr.setAttribute("align", "left");
        tr.className = "table_ce11";
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        var code = String(valueSet[i - 1]);
        td.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='pCheckBox' value='111' id ='" + code + "' onClick=\"javascript:decide('" + code + "')\">";

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}

function decide(code) {
    alert("here");
    alert(document.getElementById(code).value);
    if (document.getElementById(code).checked) alert("chked");
    else alert("unchked");
}
```

while running this, neither am able to set the id nor to pass the argument of the function `decide()`. I get the error:

> "undetermined string constraint".

But if I hardcode the values the function runs fine.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What are you passing as Result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for starters

Split creates an array.

`var valueSet = Result.split("##");`

You need to test if there ARE at least 4 items in the array

```
if (valueSet.length <= 3) return 
for (var i = 1; i < valueSet.length - 3; i++) {
```

no need to create a string when you string concatenate a string anyway

`var code = valueSet[i - 1];`

No need to use *javascript:* prefix and no need to pass the code when it is the same as the ID:

`td.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="pCheckBox" value="111" id ="' +  code + '" onClick="decide(this.id)">';`

Also default align is left and you align center on the cell so get rid of

`// tr.setAttribute("align", "left");`

can you post more of the code and tell where things are going wrong exactly?

Comment: @ mplungjan-

onClick="decide(this.id)">' worked....
now the code is working nice....thanz a lot..
this error drove me nuts...
thanq once again.